# Company still contacting me after telling them I'm not interested in the job offer

Tags: job-search, job-offer, human-resources

Over a year ago I applied for a position with Company A. I had an interview with them, but recieved a job offer from a different company shortly after it. I informed Company A that I was no longer pursuing job opportunities. Recently, my situation changed and I contacted Company A again. They basically told me to fill out paper work before I can do the next level of interview, but then they gave me a job offer and more paper work to fill out.

Initially I replied to the email saying I would take the job offer, but at the last minute changed my mind (for several reasons). By e-mail I told them I decided not to accept the offer but I also mentioned that the paper work (in particular the contract they wanted me to sign) seemed strange.

Today I got a voice mail and emails asking me to contact them so they could explain everything to me. The HR rep said she contacted my boss and they really want me on board.

I'm towards the beginning of my career, so tell me if I'm looking at this wrong, but something doesn't add up. This job pays close to minimum wage and is part time. Why would they bother to still be contacting me? (A small part of me feels that if they changed the contract I may still be interested, but I think at this point starting a job with this negativity wouldn't be good) Could this be some sort of scam? The company isn't huge but is well established (existed since mid 2000s). Should I bother to reply to the email, and if so what should I say? The HR department is in another country and I don't want to spend money on the long distance phone calls, should I tell them this?

Comment: The HR rep from Company A contacted your boss? As in, from your current job or something?

Comment: Why are you surprised they contacted you? From their perspective you declined the offer because you thought their contract was odd. They want to reach out to explain anything that might be confusing you and try to convince you to join. This is what they are supposed to do.

Comment: If this were a scam, they'd be offering much more than minimum wage. (That's not to say there's nothing wrong or nothing worth negotiating about, though.)

Comment: If you've turned down two different job offers from this company and they're still pursuing you, it sounds like they are very interested in you and that puts you in a strong negotiating position.  It can't hurt to hear what they have to say.

Comment: @voltron123 - You should send them an email, provide a window of time where you can answer the phone, and talk to them about your concerns.  If this was me I would spend the $2 on the phone call though.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom I have trouble believing they want me if they're paying minimum wage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, they just thought the strange paper was the reason you had not to go, so they genuinely believe they can still recruit you. I see no red flag there, just an honest misunderstanding.

That being said, if you are not interested, *no matter the reason*, you don't have to spend any money. A mail answer explaining your lack of interest should leave the doubt(and if it does not, then, only then, it proves this company has problematic aspects, and you should avoid it at all costs).

Answer (score 0):

> This job pays close to minimum wage and is part time.

You can respond with

> Well if you guys really want me then let me know when that changes, as
>   I'm only interested in full-time employment at and {insert any other
>   conditions here}.  Then sit back and wait for them to up your offer.

If you're feeling particularly snarky then you can add 'Well I'd like a unicorn too' to the beginning of your response.

Comment: `If you're feeling particularly snarky then you can add 'Well I'd like a unicorn too' to the beginning of your response.` yes it's always a good idea to be snarky to people you're likely to come across again, when you're at the beginning of your career

Comment: ^^^ It's an employment negotiation and it sounds like they are trying to lowball, so there's nothing wrong with setting the expectation that you're not going to accept an offer that is considered substandard.

Comment: Well, setting up the expectation a more professional way, with non-sarcastic communication, should be possible.